# Осуществить рекурсивный обход подпапок с русскими символами и разрезать каждый .flac файл

Tags: python, файлы, python-3.x, рекурсия

Есть код:

```
def go(cur):
    for dr in listdir(cur):
        if(isdir(cur.join(dr))):
            go(cur.join(dr))
        elif(dr[-4:] == 'flac'):
            query = 'cuebreakpoints {}.cue | shnsplit -o flac {}.flac'.format(dr[-5:], dr[-5:])
            os.system(query)

x = os.getcwd()
go(x)
```

Мне нужно осуществить рекурсивный обход подпапок и разрезать каждый **.flac** файл.

Проблема в том, что в названиях папок могут содержаться русские символы. Как вы поняли, код не работает (не происходит никаких изменений). Код не работает из-за плохой локализации или проблема в чем-то еще?

P.S. Как вывести строку, переведя ее в UTF-8 перед этим?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас алгоритм неправильный, попробуйте это:

```
import os

def go(cur):
    print('go ' + cur)

    for dr in os.listdir(cur):
        abs_path = os.path.join(cur, dr)
        print('  go abs_path ' + abs_path)

        if os.path.isdir(abs_path):
            print('dir')
            go(abs_path)
        elif 'flac' in dr[-4:]:
            print('cmd file')
            # query = 'cuebreakpoints {}.cue | shnsplit -o flac {}.flac'.format(dr[-5:], dr[-5:])
            # os.system(query)

go(r'D:\Users')
```

Comment: Да, действительно, вчера поздно ночью заметил, что использую не тот join. Видимо, стоит писать почаще)

Comment: Если еще os.walk или glob для обхода папок и получения списка файлов )

Answer (score 1):

На Питоне 3, у вас в коде имена файлов уже как Unicode представлены—не только русские буквы, но ещё миллион других символов можно использовать. Подробнее [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)

Чтобы выполнить внешнюю команду для каждого flac-файла в текущем дереве директорий:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys

for path in pathlib.Path().glob("**/*.flac"):
    paths = [shlex.quote(str(p)) for p in (path.with_suffix('.cue'), path)]
    command = "cuebreakpoints {} | shnsplit -o flac {}".format(*paths)
    process = subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
    if process.returncode != 0:
        print('warning: failed to split {path}, '
              '`{command}` returned {process.returncode}'.format(**vars()),
              file=sys.stderr)
```

`shlex.quote()` используется, чтобы экранировать специальные в shell символы такие как пробел в именах файлов. Если команда завершается с ненулевым статусом (ошибка), то выводится предупреждение.