# При перемещении файлов с помощью модуля shutill выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, кодировка, файлы, tkinter

При перемещении файлов с помощью модуля `shutill`: `shutill.move(path1,path2)`
Выдаёт эту ошибку:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1535, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "cleaner.py", line 88, in moveF
    moveFiles(pathdir,videos,"vid", dirnames)
  File "cleaner.py", line 70, in moveFiles
    shutil.move(path+file1, pathe3+file1)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Пути берутся с помощью Tkinter, tkFileDialog, а файлы через `os.listdir`
Пробовал использовать `path1.decode("utf-8")` и `path2.decode("utf-8")`
результат тот же.(

Comment: Для форматирования блоков кода удобно использовать отступ в четыре пробела. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к `shutil.move()`. Не нужно смешивать Unicode строки и байты:

```
>>> u"a" + "ф"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Вызывать `.encode()`, `.decode()` в слепую в надежде что это исправит ошибки, связанные с кодировкой, также не следует. Вместо этого следует чётко представлять работаете ли вы с байтами (`type(b) == str` на Питоне 2) или с Юникодом (`type(u) == unicode`).

Если окружение (локаль) правильно сконфигурировано:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'UTF-8'
```

и нет проблем с [непредставимыми именами](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/), то **используйте Юникод для имён файлов.** Никогда не смешивайте Юникод и байты -- явно преобразуйте одно в другое если необходимо. См. подробности в [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527872/23044)