# Не работает os.mkdir с русскими символами в Windows

Tags: windows, кодировка, python-2.x, unicode, файловая-система

Пытаюсь создать папки:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
f = open('dop.txt', 'r')

for line in f.xreadlines():
    print line
    os.mkdir(line)
f.close()
```

Файл `dop.txt` в кодировке UTF-8, но папку создать не удается, выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "py.py", line 15, in <module>
os.mkdir(line)
WindowsError: [Error 123] ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒,: '\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81 \xc2\xab\xd0\x90\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9\xc2\xbb\n'
```

Причем на Ubuntu этот же скрипт работает отлично. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда используйте Unicode для путей в Windows. Windows предоставляет родное Unicode API.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io
import os

with io.open('dop.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for dirpath in file:
        print(dirpath)
        os.mkdir(dirpath.strip())
```

Обратите внимание—это полный код. Подробности: [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)

> Причем на Ubuntu этот же скрипт работает отлично. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Проблем несколько:

1. `line.endswith('\n')`: в конце строки обычно символ новой строки есть `'\n'`. *nix может разрешать произвольные байты в имени файла кроме слеша `'/'` и нуля `'\0'`. На Windows, обычно [больше ограничений](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations), к примеру: `0x00-0x1F 0x7F " * / : < > ? \ |` символы зарезервированы, что включает `'\r'` (0x0D), `'\n'` (0x0A). Вызовите `dirpath.rstrip('\n')`, чтобы убрать новую строку из имени
2. Использование utf-8 вместо `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`, что скорее всего эквивалентно `cp1251` кодировке на русской Windows (utf-8 не является родной codepage ни на какой Винде), что в лучшем случае ведёт к [кракозябрам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)
3. Вообще использование байтов, вместо unicode для имён файлов. Что может вносить дополнительные ограничения на допустимые имена на Windows.

Если `print(dirpath)` строчка вызывает затруднения, то см. [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

---

В сторону: выбросьте книгу, которая вам посоветовала  `sys.setdefaultencoding()` и `f.xreadlines()` использовать (и в меньшей степени если книга советует `f.close()` вместо `with`-конструкции).