# punycode. передача пременной из bash в python в функцию encode('idna')

Tags: python, bash, кодировка, python-2.7

существует файл py1 c следующим содержанием:

```
python -c "x=u'''$1''';  print x.encode('idna')"
```

буква u, в начале значения для переменной  - это попытка привести ввод в 
bash

```
./py1 подпись.рф
```

к следующему виду в python:

```
x=u"подпись.рф"
```

так вот, при вызове скрипта получаем следующий вывод:

```
~$ ./py1 а
xn--nba1k
~$ ./py1 апо
xn--34-eea4dwnbb5725d
```

но:

```
~$ ./py1 ф
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/idna.py", line 164, in encode
result.append(ToASCII(label))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/idna.py", line 76, in ToASCII
label = nameprep(label)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/idna.py", line 38, in nameprep
raise UnicodeError("Invalid character %r" % c)
UnicodeError: Invalid character u'\x84'
```

ошибка по-видимому в данном месте

```
u'''$1'''
```

и возможно логичнее было бы воспользоваться sys.argv[] в python, однако я никак не возьму в толк, как верно вставить полученную переменную в python из sys.agr в другую, с параметром u перед строкой, пробовал следующий подход:

создается файл wpq1.py с нижеизложенным:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import sys

x= unicode(sys.argv[1])
print x
```

затем вызывается в shell:

```
~$ python wpy1.py фырфырфыр
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "wpy1.py", line 5, in <module>
x= unicode(sys.argv[1])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 
in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Зачем  вам питон? Есть стандартная утилита, которая конвертирует имена. Мешать вот так код из двух языков -- моветон

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Питоне 3 `sys.argv` уже как Unicode пришёл бы:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1].encode("idna").decode())' пример.рф
xn--e1afmkfd.xn--p1ai
```

В Питоне 2, самостоятельно аргументы командной строки из байт в текст декодировать необходимо. Для этого нужно выбрать кодировку. Для системных строк: argv, переменных окружения, путей можно `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` кодировку использовать (с оговорками):

```
$ python2 -c 'import sys; print sys.argv[1].decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()).encode("idna")' пример.рф
xn--e1afmkfd.xn--p1ai
```

На Linux `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` от локали зависит. Подробнее [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)

В общем случае, системные строки это почти произвольный набор байт, который не всегда как текст можно интерпретировать, поэтому существует `surrogateescape` обработчик ошибок, который также может активироваться на Python 3, если локаль не настроена (или неверно настроена):

```
$ LC_ALL=C python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1].encode("idna").decode())' пример.рф
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/idna.py", line 181, in encode
    result.extend(ToASCII(label))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/idna.py", line 76, in ToASCII
    label = nameprep(label)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/idna.py", line 38, in nameprep
    raise UnicodeError("Invalid character %r" % c)
UnicodeError: Invalid character '\udcd0'
```

Локаль по умолчанию (поломанные или вообще отсутствующие настройки) подразумевает ascii кодировку (С, POSIX). Поэтому при запуске init-скриптов (сервисы), при заходе по ssh, в cron-скриптах, убедитесь что локаль c нужной кодировкой определена, чтобы не-ascii содержимое такое как IDN обрабатывать. Иначе ошибку получите:

```
$ LC_ALL=C python2 -c 'import sys; print sys.argv[1].decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()).encode("idna")' пример.рф
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Если вы решите жёстко прописать кодировку такую как `utf-8`, то будьте уверены на 100%, что имена доменов у вас всегда всегда в этой кодировке генерируются в окружении, где вы запускаете ваш Питон-скрипт. Иначе или UnicodeDecodeError или хуже [кракозябры получите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044), что приведёт к генерации неверного punycode (что вы можете не сразу заметить, что удорожает исправление ошибки).

Answer (score 3):

Не особо много знаю о пайтоне, но, погуглив документацию, заметил, что функция `unicode` имеет второй параметр для указания кодировки. Так что вот такой вариант рабоает в моей консоли (Ubuntu 16.04, UTF-8):

```
import sys

x = unicode(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8')
print x
print x.encode('idna')
```

Comment: странно, но у меня следующий вывод:

import.im6: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368.
./wpy1.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./wpy1.py: line 3: `x = unicode(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8')'

Comment: @EnginerRod Как запускали? Я - `python foo.py фыва`.

Comment: все отлично, скопировал полностью код - все заработало, благодарю!

Comment: Если на 100% не известно в какой кодировке имена доменов передаются в окружении, в котором скрипт запускается, то лучше жёстко не прошивать кодировку прямо в исходном коде. Иначе если повезёт то UnicodeDecodeError получите, если не повезёт то молча неверный punycode сгенерируете. [Можно `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` кодировку использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716783/23044)