# Как определить кодировку строки (в string, а не bytes) в Python?

Tags: python, строки, кодировка

Для определения кодировки данных в bytes пользовался функцией chardet:

```
result_code = chardet.detect(data)
original_text = data.decode(result_code['encoding'])
```

Но когда переменная data - строка (string), выходит ошибка

```
TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 'str'>
```

Т.е. нужна либо другая функция для string, либо string нужно превратить в bytes.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка указывает, что у вас Питон 3, где `str` тип, используется для текста — каждая строка (str) это последовательность символов (Unicode codepoints).

Сами символы никакой кодировки не имеют (как внутри интерпретатора строки представлены не имеет значения, до тех пор пока абстракция не нарушена).

Любая кодировка, которая может представить все символы в строке, может быть использована:

```
>>> "мир".encode('utf-8')
b'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'
>>> "мир".encode('cp1251')
b'\xec\xe8\xf0'
>>> "мир".encode('cp866')
b'\xac\xa8\xe0'
>>> "мир".encode('koi8-r')
b'\xcd\xc9\xd2'
```

Сама строка никакой кодировки не имеет. Ещё примеры: [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)

Вопрос, который можно для строки задать: на каком языке вероятно текст написан? Или более узкий (определённый) вопрос: принадлежат ли все букву заданному диапазону в Unicode.

- [Python: How to determine the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39142778/4279)
- [How to match Cyrillic characters with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716609/4279)

Comment: Спасибо. Переформулирую вопрос: я не знаю в какой кодировке у меня текст, мне надо на лету определить кодировку, сменить ее для данного текста на utf-8 и дальше работать с текстом. Как это сделать в данном случае?
Исходный текст вот такой:
ІЫРбвШ єШЯаР аРббзШвлТРов ЯаШЭпвм ЯЮапФЪР

Comment: @RuslanSagitov как и откуда получен исходный текст?

Comment: Из JSON-файла.

    with open(name) as f:
          data = json.load(f)

Comment: @RuslanSagitov: [Как распознать кракозябры](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/)

Comment: @RuslanSagitov: encoding='utf-8' добавьте. Отдельный вопрос задайте: есть json, прочитал `with open(name) as f: data = json.load(f)`, получил `ІЫРбвШ єШЯаР аРббзШвлТРов ЯаШЭпвм ЯЮапФЪР` Как исправить? (и ответ скорее всего: `encoding='utf-8'` в open передать -- если это работает в вашем случае, опубликуйте ответ)

Comment: @jfs вручную можно и просто перебором вариантов, а надо на автомате определять

Comment: @RuslanSagitov: хорошо, тогда просто задайте вопрос как я показал. И подробнее кто-нибудь ответит (почему json текст обычно в utf-8 передаётся)

Comment: @jfs Спасибо, вопрос задал. Вариант с encoding='utf-8' не сработал.