# Кракозябры при чтении JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, кодировка

Есть json, прочитал:

```
with open(name) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data_join = ''
    for i in data['rss']['channel']['items']:
       data_join += ' ' + i['description']
    result = chardet.detect(data_join)
    original_text = data_join.decode(result['encoding'])
    print(original_text)
```

Если сделать `print(data_join)`, получаем:

> ІЫРбвШ єШЯаР аРббзШвлТРов ЯаШЭпвм ЯЮапФЪР

и т.д.

Если сделать `print(ascii(data['rss']['channel']['items'][0]))`, получаем что-то такое:

> \u042c\u042b\u042d \u0432\u0433\u0430\u0428\u0431\u0432\u042e\u0422 \u042f\u042e \u0428\u0432\u042e\u0423\u0420\u042c 2016 \u0423\u042e\u0424\u0420 \

На этапе `chardet.detect(data_join)` выходит ошибка:

```
TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 'str'>
```

Как исправить на автомате?
Не перебором возможных кодировок, а на лету.

Comment: явно **в вопросе** упомяните, что utf-8 не работает (и как именно: исключение получаете? Какое?). Ещё приведите значение: `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. Где вы получили кракозябры (в консоли, в файле -- чем файл открывали)? Какой результат: `print(ascii(data['rss']['channel']['items'][0]))`?

Comment: @jfs locale.getpreferredencoding() выводит cp1251
Кракозябры получаю в консоли

Comment: откуда у вас json? Почему он в iso-8859-5 закодирован?

Comment: [Как распознать кракозябры?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/)

Answer (score 1):

Если пытаться угадать кодировку файла "автоматом":

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect('ЬЫЭ вгаШбвЮТ ЯЮ ШвЮУРЬ 2016 УЮФР'.encode('cp1251'))
{'encoding': 'ISO-8859-5', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': 'Russian'}
>>> 'ЬЫЭ вгаШбвЮТ ЯЮ ШвЮУРЬ 2016 УЮФР'.encode('cp1251').decode('ISO-8859-5')
'млн туристов по итогам 2016 года'
```

то в общем случае вы можете ошибиться. Схема из устаревшей  rfc 4627 (которая, предполагая содержимое json файла, может выбрать из различных `utf-*` кодировок), не помогла бы с `iso-8859-5`. В общем случае можно только гадать (нет 100% гарантии, что правильно кодировку выбрали)
[Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044).

Если есть возможность, то исправьте источник, чтобы либо более традиционная UTF-8 кодировка для передачи json использовалась бы, либо вообще использовались бы возможности json по экранированию символов, чтобы в ASCII кодировке передать (`ensure_ascii=True`). Обе опции, в отличии от такой кодировки как `iso-8859-5`, поддерживают произвольный набор символов — весь Unicode.

Если решите продолжать `chardet` использовать, то откройте файл в бинарном режиме `open(name, 'rb')`, чтобы в `chardet.detect()` передать байты. [Строки не следует в `detect()` передавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734688/23044). Зная кодировку, превратите данные в текст и передайте в `json.loads()`.