# UnicodeEncodeError (Django)

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь указать путь загрузки файла в моделе 
`image = models.ImageField(upload_to='classes/')`
Но получаю ошибку.

Ошибка:

> UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/app/images/add/ 'locale'
>   codec can't encode character '\u0441' in position 0: Illegal byte
>   sequence

База - SQLite

Comment: похоже где-то закралась русская `с` вместо латинской `c`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, так оно и есть

Comment: чему sys.getfilesystemencoding() равно? Попробуйте в LANG envvar utf-8 локаль прописать. [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)