# Неправильно передаются параметры subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.x, subprocess

```
import argparse
import ctypes
import subprocess
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
parser.add_argument('-p', help = 'folder')
args = parser.parse_args()
path = args.p
if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0:
    print 'You admin\n'
    subprocess.call('takeown /f' + ' '  + path + ' ' + '/R  /A')
    print 'done'
else:
    print 'You not  admin'
    exit(0)
```

Запускаю так python af.py -p "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" 
[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['takeown', '/F', path, '/R', '/A'])
```

[Выдержка из документации, поясняющая почему предпочтительнее передавать список аргументов вместо строки (как раз ваш случай)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> `args` is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. **Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names).** If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

Comment: Еще хочу спросить. output2 = subprocess.check_output(['icacls', path, '/grant:r', 'Администраторы:F']). Как сделать так чтобы Администраторы отображался кириллицой  ,а не кракозябрами?

Comment: @AlexFirsov, в какой кодировке сохранен скрипт?

Comment: Сохранен в utf-8

Comment: лучше наверное задать отдельный вопрос с воспроизводимым примером...

Comment: @AlexFirsov, также советую посмотреть [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527872/211923)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в argparse. Путь содержит пробельные символы, поэтому при прямой передаче в shell интерпретируется не как один параметр, а как набор. Добавьте экранирование или используйте способ, указанный @MaxU