# TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python

Есть папка с файлами, нужно удалить все цифры в названиях файлов. Из примера все должно работать. Но у меня выкидывает ошибку. Если бы это можно было исправить- жизнь стала бы прекрасна. Добавил 2 строчки, поправил,

```
    import os
def rename_files():
    #1
    file_list=os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python Scripts\prank\prank")
    #print(file_list)

    saved_path=os.getcwd()
    print("Current Workint Directory is"+ saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python Scripts\prank\prank")

    #2
    for file_name in file_list:
        print("old name"+ file_name)
        print("New name"+ file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
        os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)

rename_files()


TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bytes.translate` и `unicode.translate` методы](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) имеют разный интерфейс. В зависимости от версии Питона [тип `str`] и наличия `from __future__ import unicode_literals` обычные строковые константы типа `'abc'` могут быть либо байтами либо Unicode. Код у вас написан, используя `bytes.translate` интерфейс, но `'abc'` это Юникодная строка на Питоне 3 и поэтому несовместимая Юникодная версия `translate` метода вызывается — запуская Питон 2 код на Питон 3, вы получаете TypeError ошибку здесь.

Используйте  Unicode пути на Windows (объяснение почему см. в [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)), тогда [в виде бонуса] код будет и на Питоне 2 так и 3 работать:

```
remove_digits_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, u"0123456789"))
no_digits = [name.translate(remove_digits_table)
             for name in os.listdir(u'C:\\Users\\name\\folder')]
```

Если передать в `os.listdir()` Unicode, то и результат будет список Unicode имён, поэтому Юникодная версия translate() метода на обоих версиях вызывается, которая принимает словарь: номер символа -> строка на что заменить или `None`, чтобы удалить символ:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3])
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

Если не нужно Питон 2 поддерживать, то [удобно `pathlib` модулем воспользоваться](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import string
from pathlib import Path

remove_digits_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, string.digits))
for path in Path(r'C:\Users\name\folder').iterdir():
    path.replace(path.with_name(path.name.translate(remove_digits_table)))
```

Здесь нет `os.chdir()` функции, которую стоит избегать, так как она затрудняет чтение кода и/или может препятствовать выполнению нескольких вещей одновременно в более крупных скриптах.

Comment: jfs, круто. Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ. Я думал там все проще)) А можно ли избежать этих ошибок, если применять интерпретатор 2,7 версии? И какой интерпретатор подойдет для этого? Я думал раньше, что версии 2,7 и 3,6 отличаются только способом печати print. Но теперь вижу, что там очень много отличий.

Comment: И может есть какой нибудь трансятор, переводящий код из версии 2,7 в любую другую? Или это очень сложная и никому не нужная задача, поэтому такого транслятора нет?

Comment: @AlexSapsay можно избежать, если запускать код, написанный для версии X на версии X интерпретатора. Инструменты, которые помогают Питон 2 код в Питон 3 превратить конечно есть (futurize), но как правило они требуют понимания таких отличий как что тип str в заданной версии представляет и какой тип интерфейс фактически ожидает (bytes, unicode, native)

Comment: @jfsс,cпасибо за ответ. У меня стоит на виндовс 3,6 питон, если установлю 2,7 не будет ли они ругаться и драться?)

Comment: @AlexSapsay можно ставить несколько версий Питона

Comment: jfs@,Спасибо за помощь. Проблему решил- установил питон 2,7. Все прекрасно работает!

Answer (score 1):

Пример написан для Python2, а вы запускаете на Python3, поэтому и не работает.

```
table = str.maketrans('', '', '0123456789')
for file_name in file_list:
    ...
    print('New name' + file_name.translate(table))
    ...
```