# os.listdir и кириллица

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Такой код(я опустил некоторые части):

```
    import os
    path = 'C:\Users\Алекс\Desktop\DefendMySystem'    
    files = os.listdir(path)
```

В переменной `path` есть кириллица, вот что я получаю при выполнении сценария:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 116, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 99, in main
    files = os.listdir(path)
WindowsError: [Error 3] : 'C:\\Users\\\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb0\\Desktop\
\DefendMySystem/*.*'
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Покажите переменную path. Если она не юникодная строка, попробуйте преобразовать в юникодную

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: `path = u'...'` попробуйте

Comment: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file aaaa.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: path = u'C:\Users\Алекс\Desktop\DefendMySystem'

Comment: Тогда ещё `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` в самой первой строчке файла (странно, что такая базовая вещь у вас не стоит)

Comment: path = u'C:\Users\╨б╨░╤И╨░\Desktop\Defend'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Сохраните файл в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM ._.

Comment: В sublime text: file-> save with encoding -> utf-8, cохранил, такая же ошибка

Comment: Ох, перейдите на Python 3?))

Comment: Ошибка пропадет?

Comment: А, я понял. Поменяйте в строке \ на \\ — вообще-то сочетание `\U` является особенным в питоне, вот на него и ругается, нужно экранировать вторым слэшем

Comment: Получилось, но хочу еще спросить, стоит ли переходить на python3 и почему?

Comment: Потому что Python 2, очевидно, устарел (и сдохнет через год) и имеет тонны проблем вроде вашей

Comment: @andreymal, https://pythonclock.org/ ;-)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С кодировками вечно какие-нибудь проблемы. Видимо, питон не справляется с угадыванием кодировки байтовой строки и не может корректно перевести её в кодировку файловой системы Windows.

Но в Python 2 у `os.listdir` (и некоторых других функций) есть особенность: если передать юникодную строку, то вернётся юникодный результат. При использовании юникода питон справляется с кодированием чего надо в какую надо кодировку, и никаких проблем нет.

Но начнём с того, что символ \ в строках является спецсимволом, и его нельзя ставить просто так. Его нужно экранировать так:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Алекс\\Desktop\\DefendMySystem'
```

или так:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Алекс\Desktop\DefendMySystem'
```

Сейчас `path` это байтовая строка, а для максимально корректной работы нужна юникодная. Строковый литерал можно сделать юникодым с помощью `u''`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# вот этот ↑ комментарий должен стоять в первой строке файла!
path = u'C:\\Users\\Алекс\\Desktop\\DefendMySystem'
path = ur'C:\Users\Алекс\Desktop\DefendMySystem'
```

(Естественно, сам файл в таком случае тоже должен быть сохранён в кодировке UTF-8, желательно без BOM.)

Если это не строковый литерал, то можно декодировать байтовую строку в юникодную, если известна кодировка:

```
path = path.decode('utf-8')
```

Теперь, когда юникодная строка получена, `os.listdir` будет работать без проблем:

```
print(type(path))  # → unicode
files = os.listdir(path)  # type: List[unicode]
```

---

А вот в Python 3 все строки юникодные, и там подобных проблем в принципе не бывает (кроме совсем уж специфических случаев).

[Поддержка Python 2.7 закончится в 2020 году.](https://pythonclock.org/)

Comment: не стоит про "угадывания" говорить (не только для байтовых, но и для Unicode строк не работало бы также, если бы исходный код интерпретировался бы, используя неверную кодировку)¶ Чтобы использовать не-ascii символы в исходном коде Питона, достаточно указать кодировку (наверху, как у вас явно в ответе показано) и не менее важно сохранить файл (исходный код) именно в этой кодировке (то есть если utf-8 указано, то не следует в блокноте в cp1251 сохранять -- получатся кракозябры)¶ Совершенно верно, что на Windows стоит Unicode для путей использовать.