# Вход по папкам по очереди

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть папки 1, 2, 3. Нужно, чтобы скрипт заходил в папки по очереди и выполнял некоторые действия. Я пытаюсь делать через while, но не знаю как вернуться в корневую папку после того как зашел в нужную и сделал операцию.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import sys, os, glob
x = 1
while x <= 3:
    x = x + 1
    os.chdir(x)
else:
    print (x,' not 4')
```

Comment: `chdir("..")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
import os

folders = ['1', '2', '3']
for folder in folders:
    os.chdir(folder)
    subprocess.call('pwd', shell=True) 
    subprocess.call('touch file', shell=True)
    os.chdir('..') # возвращение на одну папку 
print('Finished!')
```

С помощью subprocess мы работаем с командами для терминала.В данном случае `pwd`,чтобы узнать в какой директории мы находимся, а `touch file` для создания файла. В итоге в каждой папке по файлу.

Answer (score 1):

[`os.chdir()` функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) манипулирует глобальным для процесса состоянием. В общем случае, предпочтительно её избегать (как и изменение других глобальных переменных) и вместо этого *явно пути передавать*, где необходимо. К примеру:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['command', 'arg 1'], cwd='нужная/папка')
```

Ещё пример: чтобы вызвать функцию для каждого flac-файла в текущем дереве директорий, [можно обойти `Path().rglob('*.flac')` коллекцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595615/23044). Чтобы получить путь к родительской директории, вы просто используете свойство `parent`: [`path.parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent), не переходя никуда:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path.home()
>>> path.parent
PosixPath('/home')
```