# Работа с директориями

Tags: python

Возник вопрос. Необходимо спарсить данные из файлов определенного расширения, которые находятся в разных папках на диске. Как с помощью python'а пробегаться по папкам и проваливаться в них со считыванием файлов определенного формата? Думал задать переменной корневую папку и потом с помощью библиотеки os и isdir конкатенировать имя папки. Но может есть решение проще?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494396/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: https://youtu.be/lZs9opgPwjo В этом видеоуроке решается задача похожая на вашу

Comment: "Разрешения" это "расширения"?

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, виноват. Спал меньше 2 часов, мозг забагал... Конечно же, речь идет о расширении

Comment: from glob import glob

Comment: @Alexander, спасибо!